# Getting multiple error message (related to gradle) during flutter run

Tags: flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab.jar (io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab)
> to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\94c065a96316af7856a75b110bf34124\jetified-flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6697cfdd11e9fefb1f002637ca986f5e\jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a8ccdc10d176ccbaeffe0deff7255b0d\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a8ccdc10d176ccbaeffe0deff7255b0d\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a8ccdc10d176ccbaeffe0deff7255b0d\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a8ccdc10d176ccbaeffe0deff7255b0d\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a8ccdc10d176ccbaeffe0deff7255b0d\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform savedstate-1.0.0.aar (androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\80c3a606213dbaa6c8d6751b30060c6b\jetified-savedstate-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f0e67a5ff0b64c3f01996b08cfe79331\lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\e289b8ce588677189c7a903e7a871c8e\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.2.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common\2.2.0\4ef09a745007778eef83b92f8f23987a8ea59496\lifecycle-common-2.2.0.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform core-runtime-2.0.0.aar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1c3d820332c96bb0d7ac5d041f9df129\core-runtime-2.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform core-runtime-2.0.0.aar (androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1c3d820332c96bb0d7ac5d041f9df129\core-runtime-2.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.arch.core\core-common\2.1.0\b3152fc64428c9354344bd89848ecddc09b6f07e\core-common-2.1.0.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform versionedparcelable-1.1.0.aar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6132cf02908874062e7e5c2d3f8c0960\versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.collection\collection\1.1.0\1f27220b47669781457de0d600849a5de0e89909\collection-1.1.0.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b0ab52f0c5c1a5e299cc41c06ca91149\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b0ab52f0c5c1a5e299cc41c06ca91149\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b0ab52f0c5c1a5e299cc41c06ca91149\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> \collection-1.1.0.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b0ab52f0c5c1a5e299cc41c06ca91149\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b0ab52f0c5c1a5e299cc41c06ca91149\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Sam.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b0ab52f0c5c1a5e299cc41c06ca91149\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

BUILD FAILED in 6m 40s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       418.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[flutter doctor -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AUm1.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by deleting all the subfolders in .gradle present under users in Windows
And the rebuilding the app from start
So that the sub directories in .gradle got downloaded again.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: This already exists in the build.gradle file